# Using CordovaCapture to record and play the video locally in ionic

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to show this video on my app using CordovaCapture in Ionic app.
I'm also using window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL to get the video URL but still not working please go through my code and help me.

controller.js

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])

.controller('VideoCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCapture) {

function successCallback(fileEntry) {
$scope.video = fileEntry.nativeURL;
console.log(fileEntry.name);
console.log(fileEntry);
console.log($scope.video);
}
function errorCallback(fileEntry) {
    console.log(fileEntry.name);
}
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
var i, path, len;
for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {

    // do something interesting with the file
    $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL($scope.path, successCallback, errorCallback);
      console.log($scope.path);
    });
    console.log($scope.path);
}
};

// capture error callback
var captureError = function(error) {
navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};


    var options = { limit: 1, duration: 15 };

// start video capture
$scope.captureVideo = function() {
    // Launch device video recording application, 
    navigator.device.capture.captureVideo(captureSuccess, captureError, options); 

}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
      <title></title>

      <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

      <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
      <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

      <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
      <script src="cordova.js"></script> 

      <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>--> 

      <!-- your app's js -->
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
      <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
    </head>



    <body ng-app="starter">

  <ion-view ng-controller="VideoCtrl">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">My videos</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-content>
      <div class="list">
      <div class="item item-divider">
        <i class="ion-videocamera"></i>
        Current clip
      </div>
  {{video}}
      <video width="320" height="240" controls ng-if="path"> -->
        <source ng-src="{{video}}"  type="video/mp4">
       Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>

    </ion-content>

    <ion-footer-bar align-title="center" class="bar bar-light">
      <div class="button-bar">
        <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="captureVideo()">
          Capture a video
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-footer-bar>

  </ion-view>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I don't know whether I'm doing it right or wrong. Please help me how to make it work on the view.